# Java Regex - how to get all occurences inside the cbrackets in string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get all occurences (text inside the cbrackets with cbrackets) from string.

I tried to do it by this way:

```
            String DATA = "ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets\n" +
                    "driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1\n" +
                    "update_config=1\n" +
                    "device_name=P580_ROW\n" +
                    "manufacturer=LENOVO\n" +
                    "model_name=Lenovo \n" +
                    "model_number=Lenov\n" +
                    "serial_number=hjhjh7\n" +
                    "device_type=10-0050F204-5\n" +
                    "os_version=01020300\n" +
                    "config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button\n" +
                    "p2p_no_group_iface=1\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "network={\n" +
                    "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                    "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                    "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                    "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                    "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                    "    priority=1\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "network={\n" +
                    "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                    "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                    "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                    "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                    "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                    "    priority=1\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "network={\n" +
                    "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                    "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                    "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                    "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                    "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                    "    priority=1\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "network={\n" +
                    "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                    "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                    "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                    "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                    "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                    "    priority=1\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "network={\n" +
                    "    ssid=\"SSID2\"\n" +
                    "    psk=\"test123456\"\n" +
                    "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                    "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                    "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                    "    priority=19\n" +
                    "}";

            String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
            String re2="(\\{.*?\\})";   // Curly Braces 1
            List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1 + re2, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(DATA);


            while (m.find()) {
                allMatches.add(m.group());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < allMatches.size(); i++) {
                Logger.d(allMatches.get(i).toString());
            }
```

But first found result containt unwanted chars:

[image]

And the next found occurences are returned with the **"network="** string.

How can i improve my regex to get only occurences with format?:

```
{whole content in cbracket}
```

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: Why did you decide to make `re1` and `re2` that way?

Comment: I used following service:
http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3

Comment: @Mena I think, that it cannot be useful in my case or not?

Comment: To get the text in capture group 1 use `allMatches.add(m.group(1));`. And you do not have to escape `}`.

Comment: @redrom on second thought, this doesn't look like [properly formatted] JSON, so as you say a parser would not help - sorry.

Comment: @redrom Are you trying to only get what's inside the curly brackets, with the curly brackets surrounding it?

Comment: Please check if [this code](https://ideone.com/Njogq8) works on your end.

Comment: I have no idea what you were *trying* to do there, but by saying `re1 + re2`, that makes your regex `.*?(\\{.*?\\})`, which will obviously start at the beginning, matching everything until it finds a `}` after a `{`. You probably want to just use `re2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to get the curly brackets and what's inside, you can try this:

```
//                           | escaped opening bracket
//                           |  | any character, 0+ times
//                           |  |   | closing bracket
//                           |  |   |   | dot will also match new lines
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?}", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(DATA);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

With your given input, it will print:

```
{
    ssid="test1"
    psk="154695"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    sim_slot="-1"
    imsi="none"
    priority=1
}
{
    ssid="SSID2"
    psk="test123456"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    sim_slot="-1"
    imsi="none"
    priority=19
}
```

**Notes**

- What I did here was basically just remove the first part of your `Pattern`, which would match the "unwanted" text.
- This would fail (and in fact, regex would not be the solution) if you had more complex inputs, i.e. with nested levels of curly brackets or curly brackets within the curly brackets.

Comment: Thank You, it works like a charm. Text for processing is simple without inner cbrackets inside the cbrackets.

Comment: What is worthy of note is that the original regex also worked, just the value was in the `group(1)`.